# Flip scroll view with zoomed image in iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, flipview

I am having 2 scrollviews which have imageviews inside it,

Following is the hierarchy, View  --  ScrollView -- UIImageView -- Image

I have added pinch to zoom functionality, so that the user can zoom in,zoom out the image.

Now, while flipping the scrollview, if the image has been zoomed and i flip the view to backscrollview, i want the image to be reset to its original position.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the UIScrollView delegate method:`scrollViewWillBeginDragging`.
This tells you when a scrolling is going to begin. At this point you can reset the zoom and the position:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   scrollView.zoomScale = 1
   scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}
```

(swift code but similar in objc)

Comment: :but my content size of scrollview has been increased because of zoom level increase. How do I handle that?

Comment: mmh... perhaps more questions. You have 2 scrollviews: how do you go from one scrollview to the other? Do you want that when you switch from one scrollview to the other the image inside the destination scrollview is positioned at (0,0), also if it is zoomed?

Comment: fliping from one scroll view to other using flip transition. Now what i want to acheive is that if 1st scroll view has been zoomed to following parameters,didZoom: ZoomScale: 2.73; ContentSize: {873.06712103179188, 1375.0807156250723}; ScrollView: {320, 504}. I want the back view to also set its parameters to the same size with a different image zoomde to the same level as first one is

Comment: Are the two scrollviews in the same view controller? If yes, why can't you simply apply the scroll_1 contentOffset and zoomScale value to the scroll_2 contentOffset and zoomScale when scroll_2 appears.

Comment: Hi Walfer, after a lot of playing around, i went for reseting the zoomScale of scrollview to 1.0 so that the view resets to default.Now, another problem I am facing is that i want to move the reset zoomscale code to completion block of flip animatin so that it doesnt look sloppy. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you show your "reset zoomscale code"? When do you call it?

Comment: I call it on tap gesture recognizer. I do scrollview.zoomscale = 1.0 and then do the animation(flip from front view to back view)

Comment: Which function do you use to do the animation: animateWithDuration(_ duration: NSTimeInterval,
                         delay delay: NSTimeInterval,
                       options options: UIViewAnimationOptions,
                    animations animations: () -> Void,
                    completion completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)